# How to convert a csv file to grid with Xarray?

Tags: python, csv, pixel, python-xarray

I have a csv file that have many columns. I want to define Lat, Lon and time columns as dimensions and other columns set as variables in Xarray dataset. Between each point (eah pair Lat and Lon) to other there is 10 km distance. In below code I can not define pixel size in dataframe. Is it possible do that?

**sample file** : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lwzrkiqn2rxxrp/file_2018-01-01_01.csv?dl=0

**Code**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xarray

path = r'/path/file' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

colnames = ['time','Lat','Lon','Alt','Temperature', 'Relative Humidity', 'Wind speed', 'Wind direction', 'Short-wave irradiation']
for filename in all_files:
    namecsv = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, error_bad_lines=False, names = colnames, sep=',')
    df["time"]= pd.to_datetime(df["time"]) 

    xr = df.set_index(['Lat', 'Lon', 'time']).to_xarray()

    # add variable attribute metadata
    #xr['time'].attrs={'units':'hours since 2018-01-01'}
    xr['Lat'].attrs={'units':'degrees', 'long_name':'Latitude'}
    xr['Lon'].attrs={'units':'degrees', 'long_name':'Longitude'}
    xr['Alt'].attrs={'units':'m', 'long_name':'depth'}
    xr['Temperature'].attrs={'units':'k', 'long_name':'Air Temperature'}
    xr['Relative Humidity'].attrs={'units':'%', 'long_name':'Air Relative Humidity'}
    xr['Wind speed'].attrs={'units':'m/s', 'long_name':'Wind speed'}
    xr['Wind direction'].attrs={'units':'deg', 'long_name':'Wind direction'}
    xr['Short-wave irradiation'].attrs={'units':'Wh/m2', 'long_name':'Short-wave irradiation'}

    # Save NetCDF file
    xr.to_netcdf('/path/to/save/' + namecsv + '.nc')
    del namecsv, df, xr
```

**Plot**

```
import xarray as xr
da = xr.open_dataset('/home/file_2018-01-01_01.csv.nc').load()

da.Temperature[0].plot(yincrease=False)
```

**Result**

[image]

**What is I want:**

[image]

Comment: Xarray's data model does not (inherently) understand the concept of pixel size. For gridding point observation, you need something on top of xarray, such as https://www.fatiando.org/verde

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Sorry I am new in Xarray, but I am interested to use it for my geospatial data analysis. When I open NetCDF files example that downloaded from xarray user guide addresses, their map plot is normal, but it fails for my NetCDF file.

Comment: You have a lot of missing values in your data - basically, the number of unique longitude points is 175, unique latitude points 200, but the number of data points is only 980. Therefore, the image that you see after conversion is expected and correct. What you could do, is that you make new df (called df_interp), which has 200*175 (35000) points and which consists of interpolated data from using df and which will be written into netcdf.